# Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, sqlite, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my rails app to my VPS. But I'm running into an error.

```
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile.
```

In my `gemfile` I have `gem 'sqlite3'`

I've removed the `gemfile.lock` and did a `bundle install` and `bundle update`. On my git repository I can see the `gem 'sqlite3'` in my gemfile and in my lock. But when I deploy the project I still get that error.

Comment: What is the output of `sqlite3` from the command line?

Comment: It seems that deploy isn't grabbing the updated gemfile. When I go to `cd /home/deploy/wisemonkeys/releases/20141103154026` and open the Gemfile, it's not the one from my git repository, but an older one. Guess I'll destroy and remake the droplet.

Comment: Are you sure you have committed the changes to your git repo?  I have made a very similar mistake when pushing changes to heroku.

Comment: Yea, like I said. On the repo (master, same branch as local) my gemfile and gemfile lock were updated. I guess I messed up, because first I was deploying from a different Repo, I moved it to my own repo but the gemfile got stuck on the old repo. It's fine now.